# Smart Card Logon & next hop SSO RDP Login

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, single-sign-on, smartcard

I started to expriement with smart card based login. So far I can logon to my local PC using my smart card.

What doesn't work is using sso when connecting via RDP to another server. I get the error message "Der Anmeldeversuch ist fehlgeschlagen" (translates to: "The logon attempt failed"). The security eventlog of the server does not show anything related.

When using my password for logon sso works.

Am I missing somenthing for sso to work with a smartcard based logon? If I understood correctly, I should be able to use sso in combination with a smart card.

Comment: are you redirecting the smart card in remote desktop?

Comment: yes, the smart card is redirected. But works only if a driver is installed. The minidriver does not seem to work. It's an Athena  IDProtect Key USB Token V2J